# How to read a .csv file into an array list in java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an assignment for college that requires I take data from a .csv file and read it, process it, and print it in three separate methods.  The instructions require that I read the data into an array list I have written some code to do so but I'm just not sure if I've done it correctly.  Could someone help me understand how exactly I am supposed to read the file into an array list?

my code:

```
public void readData() throws IOException { 
    int count = 0;
    String file = "bank-Detail.txt";
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            bank.add(line.split(","));

            String[][] v = (String[][]) bank.toArray(new String[bank.size()][12]);

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a fixed schema for the file that you are reading?

Comment: @Kot the file is 600 or so lines with 12 comma separated parts each

Comment: You should note an Array of strings and an ArrayList are not the same thing. If the instructions require an ArrayList then you should look into that class.

Comment: Do you need  to be able to handle quotation marks correctly?  These can be used around a field in CSV, and they need to be used if a field contains a comma.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need `2D` array to store the file content, a list of String[] arrays would do, e.g:

```
public List<String[]> readData() throws IOException { 
    int count = 0;
    String file = "bank-Detail.txt";
    List<String[]> content = new ArrayList<>();
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            content.add(line.split(","));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      //Some error logging
    }
    return content;
}
```

Also, it's good practice to declare the `list` locally and return it from the `method` rather than adding elements into a shared `list` ('bank') in your case.

Comment: Nice, but cooler having the separator as a parameter as for CSV, its not always comma.