# Reading CSV file into an ArrayList<Student> java

Tags: java

Student asking for help.

I have a CSV file in the format (studentID,lastName,firstName,finalMark,finalGrade). I am trying to read this into a List of type Student / ArrayList of type Student - trying to add each line as a new Student. I have a Student class implementing Comparable for sorting the file. This Student class has these five (studentID,lastName,firstName,finalMark,finalGrade) as the Constructor.

Can someone please demonstrate/show me, through code and/or explanation, how to read from the file, into the List using FileReader and BufferedReader or (second preference) Scanner.

```
public static ArrayList <String> readAllLinesFromFile(String path) throws IOException {

        // System.out.println("Cannot locate input file");

        ArrayList<String> studentList = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("Question4unorderedList.csv");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line = null;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
            studentList.add(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return studentList;
    }
```

So I can create an ArrayList of type String. But how can I convert/parse/translate this ArrayList of Strings into a List or ArrayList of Student (my Student Class Constructor details are above).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What did you try so far? Any error you faced?

Comment: That's not the way it works: you haven't even try to do it. There are plenty of example on internet.Try coding before asking for something.

Comment: Take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170837/how-to-read-a-csv-file-into-an-array-list-in-java

Comment: reading csv could be a nightmare. search for a lib on internet and try it.

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List <Student> studentList = new ArrayList <>();
    String fileIn = "Question4unorderedList.csv";
    String fileOut = "Question4orderedList.csv";
    String line = null;

    // Read all lines in from CSV file and add to studentList
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileIn);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] temp = line.split(",");
        int studentID = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
        String firstName = temp[1];
        String lastName = temp[2];
        int finalMark = Integer.parseInt(temp[3]);
        String finalGrade = temp[4];
        studentList.add(new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, finalMark, finalGrade));
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
```