# how to read csv file by (tab) and store file to arraylist by java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, io, filereader

I'm a beginner at java programming. I need help how to read a csv file by (tab) and store file to ArrayList and how to read a specific cell from the file.
Here's my code:

```
    public static void main (String[] args){
           String file_Name = "info.txt";
               File file = new File(file_Name);
           try {

               Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
                while (inputStream.hasNext()){
                    String data = inputStream.next();
                    String [] values;
                    String delimeter;
                   delimeter = "\tab";
                   values = data.split(delimeter);

                }
                inputStream.close();

           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

       }
```

```
text file
Sweater gold    55.5 
Jeans   silver  68.5  
Hat gold    20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The tab delimeter is '\t' not '\tab'. if you need to read specific cell in an excel you need to use a library like apache poi

Comment: How to store file to arraylist, could you help me, please?

Comment: @ayoubosman - does this answer your question? [How to read a .csv file into an array list in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170837/how-to-read-a-csv-file-into-an-array-list-in-java)